# Why do partially closed generics work when running in a Function but not when calling ServiceCollection directly?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, .net-core, azure-functions

I just attempted to use partially closed generic DI registration for the first time using dotnet 3.1, v3 Azure functions and 3.1.8 of MS DependencyInjection package - all the latest at the time of writing.

The types are resolved as hoped when set as constructor dependencies. However, when I call GetService<> on the container directly I get an `ArgumentException`:

> The number of generic arguments provided doesn't equal the arity of the generic type definition

If I saw this error during runtime I'd conclude that partially closed generics aren't supported, but this isn't the case and I can't figure out why.

```cs
public interface IMyInterface<TypeA, TypeB>
{

}

public class MyClass<TypeA> : IMyInterface<TypeA, MyConcreteTypeB>
{
}

services.AddSingleton(typeof(IMyInterface<,>), typeof(MyClass<>));

var myObject = services
   .BuildServiceProvider()
   .GetService<IMyInterface<MyConcreteTypeA, MyConcreteTypeB>>();

myObject.Should().Be().OfType<MyClass<MyConcreteTypeA>>();
```

I can't run the (rough) code above as a unit test but I can resolve `IMyInterface<MyConcreteTypeA, MyConcreteTypeB>` as a constructor param in an Azure Function.

Update:

Working example: https://github.com/mr-panucci/sandbox

Comment: Just put together a working sample using VS Http Functions template - link in question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an interesting question. The reason it works in Function constructor is because internally Function Host uses [DryIoc](https://github.com/dadhi/DryIoc) as DI container implementing a custom service provider of `Microsoft.DependencyInjection`. DryIoc container in turn supports resolving partially closed generic types. You can explore the Function Host DI wiring [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/tree/dev/src/WebJobs.Script.WebHost/DependencyInjection).

Now to solve your problem of unit test to simulate the same behavior of Function host here:

1. Add nuget [DryIoc.Microsoft.DependencyInjection](https://www.nuget.org/packages/DryIoc.Microsoft.DependencyInjection/) to your test project.
2. Update the test code like below:

```
services.AddSingleton(typeof(IMyInterface<,>), typeof(MyClass<>));

var myObject = DryIocAdapter.Create(services).BuildServiceProvider() // using DryIoc.Microsoft.DependencyInjection;
                 .GetService<IMyInterface<MyConcreteTypeA, MyConcreteTypeB>>();

myObject.Should().Be().OfType<MyClass<MyConcreteTypeA>>();
```